# what is wrong with datetime.strptime() not working in this case?

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to convert this string into a date:

> My Birthday, 11/07/2022

here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime

with open('events.txt') as file:
        for line in file:      # sample of the line is the string above
            ## split events by comma
            current_event = line.split(',')
            ## convert second item from str into date
            event_date = datetime.strptime(current_event[1], "%d/%m/%Y").date()
```

it give me this error:

```
ValueError: time data ' 28/10/2022' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

Comment: Did you notice the initial space character in the string `' 28/10/2022'`?

Comment: `current_event = line.split(', ')` would remove the space.

Comment: yes, that was exactly the bug

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

`str.strip` with no arguments removes any whitespace before or after a string.

```
with open('events.txt') as file:
        for line in file:      # sample of the line is the string above
            ## split events by comma
            name, date = line.split(',')
            ## convert second item from str into date
            event_date = datetime.strptime(date.strip(), "%d/%m/%Y").date()
```